# Migrating Django from 1.9 to 1.11: forms.MultiWidget.format_output disappeared

Tags: django, django-forms

This method was very usefull to render `MultiWidget` in Django 1.9:

```
format_output(rendered_widgets)
```

I use it in many places, here is an example of use:

```
def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
    items = [ '%s %s' % (rendered_widgets[i], f)
                            for (i,f) in enumerate(self.fieldnames) ]
    if self.aligned:
        return '<li>' + '</li><li>'.join(items) + '</li>'
    else:
        return ' '.join(items)
```

It disappears in Django 1.11, and I don't find a natural replacement. The `render` method seems to be the unique alternative, but I don't understand how to use it correctly.

Does anybody have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution that seems to work:

```
#~ def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
    if not value:
        value = [ False for x in self.fieldnames ]
    rendered_widgets = [ x.render(name, value[i]) for i,x in enumerate(self.widgets) ]
    ... # rest is the same
```

**EDIT:**

In fact, no, it does not work. The `rendered_widgets` calculation must be:

```
rendered_widgets = [ x.render('%s_%d' % (name,i), value[i]) for i,x in enumerate(self.widgets) ]
```

I spent too much time on this problem, this is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452755/migrating-django-from-1-9-to-1-11-trouble-with-multivaluefield-and-multiwidget/46492191#46492191).
**But why `format_output` has been removed ???**

Answer (score 0):

Don't care for format_output. Just inherit from `django.forms.widgets.MultiWidget` and use this method:
`get_context(self, name, value, attrs)` defined in django/forms/widgets.py

In the method extending this you may define your contextual values. 
To find out what fields it has, simply call the upper one with `super().get_context(name, value, attrs)` and do:
`print(context)`.
All data comes under "widget" field and its sub-fields, including the field "subwidgets".

To set a template for this widget, set `template_name` property in the class body. By default it is set to: 
`template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/multiwidget.html'`

In the widget template, you now have the access to subwidgets as 
`widget.subwidgets.X`, where `X` is the index starting with 0. This template variable contains the data dict only (you can print the contents in your template by referring it directly, eg. 
`{{ widget.subwidgets.0 }}`
To get the sub-widget formatted for display, just do:
`{% include widget.subwidgets.0.template_name with widget=widget.subwidgets.0 %}`

Of course you can iterate the subwidgets if you wish, in my case this wasn't an option.

You can read more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Widget.get_context
And here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful by adding a complete code example summarizing everything you're describing.